# Confused on which RAM is compatible with two dimm slot

Tags: windows-7

I need some advice. I have a MOBO (Gigabyte GA-MA78LMT-S2) with two dimm slot (1333). Can I install **two** 4GB RAM (not a kit) into my MOBO? I want to max it to 8Gb RAM. Right now I'm using 2x2GB KIT RAM (CORSAIR).

Comment: Unless you are currently using Windows 7 x64 purchasing more then 4GB of memory is a waste of your money.

Answer (score 1):

Practically yes, assuming your motherboard supported the same type of ram as you have bought and supports 8gb (which it seems to).

Kits just ensure you have two sticks of the same brand and specification, which means that in general, you definately can do dual channel memory. Getting two identical sticks not as part of a kit should work as well.

Comment: You don't really save any money by ordering two identical sticks of memory outside of a kit unless there isn't a sale on the kit and there is on a single peice of memory.

Answer (score 1):

These so-called *kits* simply consist of two normal and identical RAM modules.

If both modules are identical, it **will** work.

As long as both modules are DDR3 1333, it **should** work, but different latencies etc. can cause problems.

Comment: Plenty of 1066/1333 "kits" contain three sticks these days, for the same reasons, only in a triple-channel configuration. :)